# Detect specific application launch event

Tags: android

According to the posts I have read, We can achieve this

1. By creating a background service and polling all the running tasks and looping through them to find that application is running or not
2. Checking through log cat to find an Intent for that application is started or not

But the problem is both methods have to run in time intervals periodically which is battery consuming. Is there anyway to detect that specific app(package name is known) is launched or not except above methods. It seems like there is no broadcast receiver for app launching events. I can't understand why android not supported for this use case without a bit of hack while this is a valid use case.right?